# My window closes immediately after opening even though I have a loop that prevents that, using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to get my little purple circle to move but after I put in the movement the window closes immediately after opening when it did not do this before. this is one of my first experiences with pygame and programming as a whole.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600

purple = (160, 32, 240)
white = (255, 255, 255)

x = 50
y = 50
vel = 5

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("First game")

screen.fill(white)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys(pygame.K_LEFT):
        x -= vel

    if keys(pygame.K_RIGHT):
        x += vel

    if keys(pygame.K_UP):
        y -= vel

    if keys(pygame.K_DOWN):
        y += vel

    
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (purple), [400, 300], 20, 0)
    

    pygame.display.flip()
    
pygame.quit()
```

I tried googling answers but they did not help me, so ofc I come to stack overflow for help.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: `key` is not a function, but iterable. So `keys[pygame.K_LEFT]` instead of `keys(pygame.K_LEFT)`. You will receive an error message at this point and your application will end with a TypeError